# How do you list all the submitters of a path (including sub-directories) on P4 CLI?

Tags: perforce

I'm looking for a command like this pseudo-query

`SELECT DISTINCT Submitted_By FROM Submitted_Changelists WHERE CONTAINS(File_path, "/depot/path/to/branch/mydir/");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p4 changes -s submitted //depot/path/to/branch/mydir/... \
| cut -d ' ' -f 6 \
| cut -d '@' -f 1 \
| sort -u`

Breakdown:

1. `p4 changes -s submitted //depot/path/to/branch/mydir/...`: Lists change summaries for all changes to the specified path.
2. `cut -d ' ' -f 6` to extract the `username@client` part of the change summary.
3. `cut -d '@' -f 1` to extract the username part of that.
4. `sort -u` to sort the list of usernames and to remove duplicates.

Comment: The solution not only works but explains why and teaches commands I didn't know!

Answer (score 1):

```
p4 -F %user% changes //depot/path/to/branch/mydir/... | sort -u
```

Comment: Output: `Perforce client error:p4 -h for usage. Invalid option: -f.`
Server version is: 2014.1/933132. Client: Rev. P4/LINUX26X86/2008.1/158777 (2008/07/09).

Comment: @Ricardo `-f` is not the same thing as `-F`.  Case matters.

Comment: The -F option might not be available in a client from 2008 -- I'd recommend grabbing a new version of p4 (and yes, case does also matter).  :)

Comment: Actually `-F` was not there either. I tried both. But solution 1 already works. Thanks!